# Static member initialization after instantiation in clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Such code can be compiled by GCC, but clang 3.5 fails.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class C{
public:
  const static int x;
};

int main(){
  cout << C<int>::x;
}

template<>
const int C<int>::x = 4;
```

Clang returns message:

```
hello.cpp:15:19: error: explicit specialization of 'x' after instantiation
const int C<int>::x = 4;
                  ^
hello.cpp:11:19: note: implicit instantiation first required here
  cout << C<int>::x;
                  ^
```

Is the error in code, or in clang compiler? Does it fulfill the standard, or GCC is more permissive and compiles non-standard code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is wrong. C++11 14.7.3/6 says:

> If a template [...] is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
>   to take place

Your code uses it in `main`, causing an implicit instantiation there, then declares the  specialisation later, as the error message describes.

Answer (score 1):

if I recall correctly

> Specialization must be declared before the first use that would cause implicit instantiation, in every translation unit where such use occurs.

(taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) so it seems GCC is much more permissive than clang...

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
  cout << C<int>::x;       // 1
}

template<>
const int C<int>::x = 4;   // 2
```

When compiler compiles 1, it tries to specialize `C<int>` from `template <typename T> class C`. Since your template specializing is not read by compiler yet, compiler specializes `C<int>` implicitly. So, `C<int>::x` is also specialized by compiler.

And compiling 2, the `C<int>::x` is *already* specialized by compiler. You're trying specialize it twice, so it fails.

There's [live example](http://ideone.com/5dg633) which is correct. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class C{
public:
  const static int x;
};

template<>
const int C<int>::x = 4;

int main(){
  cout << C<int>::x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard tells that you need to declare specialization before using it.

So the standard behavior would be to have your declare your template intialization before the main function.

Some compilers allow more freedom in some cases, and it seems that in this scenario gcc allows a non-standard declaration.